# _ActivateRouter symbol not found loading ClipsPy on arm64 mac

Tags: python, clips

I want to utilize the CLIPS rules engine within a Python application. However, I am developing on Mac M2, so the popular wrapper clipspy is not available. What's my next best option? Are there any good ways of setting up a separate web server running CLIPS and interface via REST? Should I be writing to a file and using subprocess to call the CLIPS interpreter?

The CLIPS interpreter runs on my Mac M2, but I want a nice way to interface with it from Python.

clipspy docs specifically say it does not work on Mac M architectures. This is the error I get after pip installing and trying to import:

```
>>> import clips
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tobrien6/Dev/game/py-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clips/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from clips.environment import Environment
  File "/Users/tobrien6/Dev/game/py-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clips/environment.py", line 32, in <module>
    from clips.facts import Facts
  File "/Users/tobrien6/Dev/game/py-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clips/facts.py", line 47, in <module>
    from clips.modules import Module
  File "/Users/tobrien6/Dev/game/py-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clips/modules.py", line 40, in <module>
    from clips.common import CLIPSError
  File "/Users/tobrien6/Dev/game/py-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clips/common.py", line 33, in <module>
    from clips._clips import lib, ffi
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/tobrien6/Dev/game/py-server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clips/_clips.abi3.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ActivateRouter'
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that clipspy can't be built on arm64? If there's documentation to that effect, could you point to it -- or if you tried and failed, could you show the error as part of the question? (And in general, better to specify the architecture than the specific chip; a clipspy built for M1 or M3 would work perfectly well on your M2, since they all use the same instructions)

Comment: ...I _can_ see some places where https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/blob/master/setup.py might have unintentional platform dependencies, if f/e its list of header locations doesn't match where CLIPS installs its headers on Mac -- but all that should be straightforward to fix. Either way, _show the error_ so we can address it head-on. (If you just haven't _tried_ installing XCode and dependencies to do a local build and are only looking at which platforms have precompiled binaries on pypi, that's a separate issue, but we can only speak to that when we _know_ it's what led to your question).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've edited my post to include the information.

Comment: Hmm. A symbol being missing doesn't look like a platform-specific problem -- on its face, it smells more like a versioning problem (which is to say, whether the specific version of CLIPS and the specific version of clipspy get along with each other). Unless, of course, the ABI itself varies by architecture.

Comment: Mind, if it really is an ARM-specific problem, you can install an Intel-based Python, an Intel-based CLIPS, and use Rosetta to run them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I think I will run an Intel Docker container for clipspy, configure it with the rules I need there, and then expose the functionality I need with Flask.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [issue](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/issues/58), the MAC M support will be added once GitHub actions will support the architecture for open source projects.

In the meanwhile, you can use the Makefile and open an issue in the project if you encounter problems while compiling.